# How to use regular expression in Notepad++ to insert comma in sequence of space and digit

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to insert delimiters in a text file. In one case, I want to insert a comma before a digit. I can uniquely specify the points where I want to insert the comma in each row as a space and then a digit. Briefy, the data looks as follows:

```
Row1 Data etc etc 1234
Row2 Data etc 825
Row3 Data etc 719
```

And so on. Note that there is a bunch of various characters, and at the end of the line there is a space and then a digit of some sort. I want to use a regular expression to specify this pattern of digit then space, and then replace it with space, comma, then digit. So:

```
Row1 Data etc etc ,1234
Row2 Data etc ,825
Row3 Data etc ,719
```

I believe I have come up with the Find what field:"\s[0-9]"

However, I don't know what to put in the Replace with field. I tried "\s,[0-9]", but then it literally replaces the regular expression with the string "\s,[0-9]". How would I go about having it generically leaving the space and the digit, and only putting in the comma?

I would appreciate any advice that anyone can provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) in your search pattern and then replace with backrefenreces to these groups (and a comma) like so:

Search: `(\s)(\d)`

Replace: `$1,$2`

You might want to change your search pattern to `(\s)(\d+)$` if there is a chance to encounter numbers before your wanted position. The `$` is used as an anchor for the end of the line.